# Need an example of ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInAppDomain

Tags: c#, c++

To load assembly in default domain, I use the following code

```
    DWORD result;
    hr = pClr->ExecuteInDefaultAppDomain(
        managedDllLocation,
        L"XXX",
        L"XXX",
        L"XXX",
        &result);
```

How can I execute the code in a specific domain with ICLRRuntimeHost::ExecuteInAppDomain? I couldn't find any example online, even in [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/iclrruntimehost-executeinappdomain-method).

Does anyone have an example of ExecuteInAppDomain method?

Comment: Try using :`AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load`. [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.load?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: @Eldar OP is talking about the scenario where a _**native**_ app is _hosting the CLR itself (e.g. Managed SQL) in order to do something with the CLR_ **not** .NET code doing something in .NET.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/hosting/

Comment: Did you do it? I'd like that sample too! :)